# if i delete any id from my database in mysql then it show me the fatal error

Tags: php, mysql

The query is:

```
 DELETE id from users_question WHERE id = '$id'
```

The error is

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1109 Unknown table 'id' in MULTI DELETE' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_3\classes\class.q_a.php:53 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\project_3\classes\class.q_a.php(53): PDO->query('\r\nDELETE id \r\nf...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\project_3\classes\class.q_a.php(91): manage_user_question->delete_question('2') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\project_3\libs\question_.php(2): include_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\project_3\tutorial.php(58): include_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...') #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_3\classes\class.q_a.php on line 53
```

Comment: Please share the query

Comment: Would be helpful if you showed the actual query.

Comment: DELETE id 
from users_question
WHERE id = '$id'

Comment: Have you **read** the error reported by any chance, before posting here?

Comment: Use the correct syntax: [SQL Delete](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp).

Comment: I always find the correct, full syntax helps to help avoid errors - that means including back-ticks etc: DELETE FROM \`users_question\` WHERE \`id\` = $id;

Answer (score 3):

You have to overwrite your query like below

```
DELETE  FROM  users_question WHERE id = '$id'
//    /\ No need to write field name
```

Comment: @hasnain Please aaccept my answer if this is useful to you..... :)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong it should be:

`DELETE FROM users_question WHERE id = YOURIDHERE`

Answer (score 1):

try this query

as you have error in your query

from

```
DELETE id from users_question WHERE id = '$id'
```

to

```
DELETE from users_question WHERE id = '$id'
```

Comment: oh waaah thanks stack over flow its working now

Comment: can you accept my answer if it worked.

Comment: yes thanks syed mohammed

Comment: ok accept it by clicking the tick mark

Answer (score 0):

**Syntax**

```
DELETE FROM table_name [WHERE Clause]
```

Check Here [Delete Query - Mysql Tutorial Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-delete-query.htm)

No Need to mention ID between Delete & FROM. Remove ID.

```
DELETE  FROM  users_question WHERE id = '$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your query is wrong. it should be like this

```
DELETE FROM users_question WHERE id = YOURIDHERE
```

Check mysql delete syntax [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)